# Is the formula $\exists x [f(x) = a]$ logically valid?

Tags: functions, logic, quantifiers

Since the variable $x$ belongs to the universal set, then we could say that $f^{-1}(a)$ is one of the values we could assign to $x$. Therefore, $\exists x [(f(x) = a]$ is equivalent to $f(x_0)=a \lor f(x_1)=a \lor \ldots f[f^{-1}(a)]=a \ldots f(x_n)=a$. Since $f[f^{-1}(a)]=a$ is true, then $\exists x [(f(x) = a]$ is always valid. Is it correct?

Comment: What is $a$? You would need to assume $a$ is in the image of $f$, which is equivalent to your formula.

Comment: $a$ is an any element in the codomain of the function. In this case, the codomain is also equal to the universal set.

Comment: This is not clear.   By positing the existence of an element $f^{-1}(a)$ for each element, $a$,  in the universal set you are already assuming that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @lulu. I thought that, since the domain of $f$ is the universal set, I could substitute $x$ by any value, including $f^{-1}(a)$. As such, $f$ would be surjective, simply because its domain is the universal set. Is it possible that $f$ is not surjective for $a$, even if the domain is universal?

Comment: What does $f^{-1}(a)$ mean for an abstract function?

Comment: @lulu, I will try to give a concrete example. Let's say $f(x)=1/x$. Therefore, $\exists x[f(x) = 0]$ means $\exists x[1/x = 0]$ and $\exists x[1/0 = x]$. So, $f^{-1}(0) = 1/0$. If $x$ is a real number, then the formula would be false. But in this case, $x$ is in the universal set and $1/0$ is in the universal set. Hence, $\exists x[f(x) = 0]$ is valid.

Comment: Not following.  If you define the universal set to be $\mathbb R\cup \ \{\alpha\}$ and then define $f(x)$ to be $\frac 1x$ if $x\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$ and $f(\alpha)=0$ then, sure.  But...that is not how you defined the universal set, nor is it how you defined $f$.

Comment: I am defining here the universal set as the set that contains all elements. I am not using ZFC.

Comment: Of course not.  If $f$ is *not* surjective you *know* that isn't true.  Example: Let $\mathbb R$ be our universal set and $f(x) = x^2 +7$ and $a = 3$.  Obviously there is not $x\in \mathbb R$ so that $x^2 + 7 = 3$.  ...  Your error is not considering that $f^{-1}(a)$ could be empty.  $f^{-1}(23) =\{4,-4\}$ but $f^{-1}(3) = \emptyset$.... And $f(f^{-1}(3)) = \{f(x)| x\in \emptyset\} = \emptyset$

Comment: "I am defining here the universal set as the set that contains all elements. I am not using ZFC. "  SO..... colorless green ideas sleeping furiously are in your universal set?  What about the item $x = $an item not in the universal set.  You don't have to use ZFC but you gotta use *something*. And your universal set will *ALWAYS* lead to contradictions. (Because, by definition, it will contain everything that *isn't* in it.)

Comment: Let $f(x)=1$.  Let $w \in f^{-1}(2)$.  Then $f(w) =f(f^{-1}(2)) =2$.  But by definition $f(w) =1$.  A contradiction.

Comment: Obviously not; if $a$ is zero and function $f$ is the *successor* function, there is no number in $\mathbb N$ that is the predecessor of zero.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not and you know it.

Let the universal set be $\mathbb R$ and $f(x) = x^2$ and $a = -1$.  So is there an $x \in \mathbb R$ so that $x^2 = -1$?  No.

Your error is when you say $f(f^{-1}(a)) = a$ always.  That just is not true.

$f(f^{-1}(-1)) = (f^{-1}(a))^2 = \sqrt {-1}^2 \ne -1$ because $\sqrt{-1}$ does not exist so you can not square it.

More generally  $f^{-1}(a) = \{x| f(x) = a\}$ could very well be empty.

And if so.... $f(f^{-1}(a)) = \{f(x)| x \in f^{-1}(a)\}= \{f(x)|x\in \emptyset\} =\emptyset$.

......

Okay.  Let $U$ be your "universal set of unrestricted domain of discourse".

Now let $f(x) = \begin{cases}1& \text{if }x\in U\\x&\text{if }x \not \in U\end{cases}$

Then what is the solution to $f(x)= 2$?

As $f(x) \ne 1$ we must have $x \not \in U$.  So that means $f(x) =x$  So $f(x) = x = 2$.  So $2 \not \in U$. But $2\in U$ because surely a universal set of unrestricted domain can not be restricted to exclude $2$.  A contradiction.

....

Or more bluntly.  Let $f(x) = 1$.  Let $x\in f^{-1}(2)$.  Then $f(x) = 2$. But $f(x) =1$.  A contradiction.  Doesn't matter *which* domain we choose.

Comment: Mr @fleablood, you proved the validty of the argument $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} [f(x) = a]$, where $f(x)=x^2+7$ and $a=3$. In this case, I totally agree with you, there is no real solution to $x=\sqrt{-4}$. But if we consider an unrestricted domain of discourse, such that $\exists x [f(x) = a]$, then $x=\sqrt{-4}$ is in the universal set, which means $f^{-1}(-4)$ is not empty. The fact that the domain is equal to the universal set makes it impossible that $f^{-1}$ is empty.

Comment: I am aware that there is no universe, since an unrestricted comprehension leads to contradictions, but that is not the discussion atm.

Comment: "But if we consider an unrestricted domain of discourse"  No. Such. Thing.  That's a meaningless and inconsistent concept.

Comment: A logically valid statement must hold in **all** domains of discourse. So a single counter-example as provided by @fleablood is all that is needed to refute the logical validity of a statement. You (TylerD007) seem to be misunderstanding some basic points about first-order logic.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation, Mr @fleablood. I still got a question: you said $\sqrt{-1}^2 \neq -1$, because $\sqrt{-1}$ does not exist. Indeed, $\sqrt{-1}$ is not a real number, but it does exist (as a complex number, for example) and it belongs to the universal set. So, isn't it more accurate to say that $\sqrt{-1}^2 = -1$ holds true, but $\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{R}$ does not?

Comment: There is no universal domain.  AI function has a specific domain. If $f(x)=x^2$ with the domain $\mathbb R$ then $\mathbb R$ is the domain.  That $i\in \mathbb C$ has $f(i) =-1$ doesn't matter in the slightest bit because $i$ *is not in our domain*.  Period.  We could define $meal^2 = roast\ beef$ but we don't have $f^{-1}(roast\ beef) =meal$ because $meal$ is not in our domain. (I'm only half joking). Likewis if our domain was $\mathbb N$ the $f^{-1}(24)$ does not exist because there is no such thing in our universe of natural numbers as $\sqrt{24}$. THERE. IS. NO. UNIVERSAL. DOMAIN.

Comment: @TylerD007 It seems there is nothing that isn't in your "universal set" – including impossible, nonexistent things. The problem with not restricting discourse is that many syntactically valid terms don't denote anything.